# User is not signed out even after FirebaseAuth.instance.signout is executed

Tags: flutter

I have a streambuilder that listens for auth changes. When i sign my user out using               FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); it does seem to work. However, when i try to login with another user's credentials, the previous user's information is displayed instead.
However, I have noticed that when i hot restart my app in Android studio, the app resets itsefl and only then it presents me the new user's information.
How do i fix this?? It seems like my app's state needs to be reset after i signout, but I am not sure how to do this.
I am not storing any user value using shared prefs via provider, however i am using sharedprefs to store other information that helps the user filter information from listings.
Please advise.

Comment: Have you get any error or exception? Please use try-catch and see what's the log.

Comment: which type of auto login are you using? 
i think its not issue with signOut() , but may be with 
data, that still persit your class after signout , also which type of login are you using

Comment: @AkbarMasterpadi I am logging in with email. Hemal Moradiya I used the try and catch, but there is no error. The issue is with my app not resetting its state. This issue gets fixed when i hot restart my app manually from Android studio console. I tried to wrap my whole app in a stateful widget, but it is still not helping.

Comment: can you plz provide your signout(), login(), data() display code,

Comment: or visit  [link](https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/)

Comment: @AkbarMasterpadi I figured it out. I had my deserialized user saved outside the class therefore the user was not resetting when signing out. Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it.